# Is it possible for a WCF channel to fault right after checking the state (single thread)?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have been handing the closing and aborting of channels this way:

```
public async Task<MyDataContract> GetDataFromService()
{
    IClientChannel channel = null;
    try
    {
        IMyContract contract = factory.CreateChannel(address);
        MyDataContract returnValue = await player.GetMyDataAsync();
        channel = (IClientChannel);
        return returnValue;
    } 
    catch (CommunicationException)
    {
       // ex handling code
    } 
    finally
    {
        if (channel != null)
        {
            if (channel.State == CommunicationState.Faulted)
            {
                channel.Abort();
            }
            else
            {
                channel.Close();
            }
         }
    }
}
```

Assume only a single thread uses the channel.  How do we know the channel will not fault right after checking the state?  If such a thing were to happen, the code would try to Close() and Close() will throw an exception in the finally block.  An explanation about why this is safe/unsafe and examples of a better, safer way would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not really sure, will Close throw if the other end of the channel suddenly faults? Put a break point in just before close, shut down the service, and see if Close will throw.

Comment: Good suggestion, ill try that when I get a chance later today.  But I would have to test that for just about every channel stack I use to be safe wouldn't I?

Comment: I am heavily using WCF services in live production and have never seen any errors from the service handling classes. They have been called 2+million times in the last 8 months. It would appear that it's ok, but your question is interesting, I didn't think about it, so I never tried to find out...

Comment: "examples of a better, safer way would be appreciated". See http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/18324

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the state is a "snapshot" of the current state when you get it. In the time between when you access the CommunicationState and when you go to make a logical decision based on it, the state can have easily changed. A better WCF pattern is:

```
try
{
    // Open connection
    proxy.Open();

    // Do your work with the open connection here...
}
finally
{
    try
    {
        proxy.Close();
    }
    catch
    {
        // Close failed
        proxy.Abort();
    }
}
```

In this way you don't rely on the state in order to make decisions. You try to do the most likely thing (a healthy close) and if that fails (which it will when the CommunicationState is Faulted), you call Abort to ensure proper cleanup.